# Azure WordPress deny access to xmlrpc

Tags: htaccess, xml-rpc

I am trying to disable `xmlrpc.php` by using a plugin and also by using `.htaccess`. But it doesn't seem to be working, when I hit `example.com/xmlrpc.php` I still get the following:

> XML-RPC server accepts POST requests only.

I'm trying this in `.htaccess` file:

```
# Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>

# BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API" and "END DS-XML-RPC-API" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END DS-XML-RPC-API
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you tried? What specific setting in .htaccess are you using? Is your server setup with Apache?

Comment: # Block WordPress xmlrpc.php requests
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>

Comment: # BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN DS-XML-RPC-API" and "END DS-XML-RPC-API" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

# END DS-XML-RPC-API

Comment: i was trying these

Comment: Thanks! Can you please edit these into your question? So all information is in there and not in the comments. You're mentioning Azure in the title, are you hosting the server yourself?

Comment: No, i am not hosting the server by myself